# Can't checkout svn repository using the SVN vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, svn

I am trying to checkout a SVN repository using the [SVN extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm) for vscode on windows with SlikSvn installed. When I try to checkout, after indicating the url of the repository and the local folder, the extension get stuck on the "checkout svn repository" notification and I am never prompted to give my svn password.

I have the following svn output:

```
Using svn "1.14.2-SlikSvn" from "svn"
[test]$ svn checkout svn+ssh://<myurl> c:\<myfolder>
```

When I try the same command `svn checkout svn+ssh://<myurl> c:\<myfolder>` on the command line I am prompted to give my password and can checkout without problem. I imagine that the problem must come from the SVN vscode extension.

Comment: Have you tried using the environment variables SVN_USERNAME and SVN_PASSWORD?